# html entities decode angular

Tags: html, angularjs, mean, sanitize

I am trying to decode html entities in Angular, and seen some solutions for some strings with Sanitize, but I have a lot of JSON documents in my db with that I need sanitized. How can I do this? Right now my html shows the full

```
<h2>Badkamer</h2>
```

inclusive the tags.

This is a part of my json document

```
{  
"badkamer" : {
    "content" : "<h2>Badkamer</h2>"
                   <p>text</p>
   }
}
```

This is my angular controller

```
app.controller('DataCtrl', ['$sce', function($scope,$http,$sce){
   $scope.specials = function(){
   $scope.special = [];

 $http.get('/specialdata').then(function(d){
   $scope.special = d.data[0];
   console.log(d.data);
  },function(err){
   console.log(err);
  });
 };
}]);
```

This is the page where I show my data from MongoDB

```
<div class="align-content-inner">
   <div>
      {{special.badkamer.content}}
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: try `<div ng-bind-html="special.badkamer.content"> </div>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include `angular-sanitize.js` script in HTML, and `ngSanitize` module on your app.,
Like :

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngSanitize']);
```

and use `ng-bind-html` [directive.](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml)., like:

```
<div ng-bind-html="special.badkamer.content"></div>
```

See this [demo plunker.](https://plnkr.co/edit/SWbFWCWOtLBN9JjznM6k?p=preview)